# parsing xml Qstring using QXmlStreamReader qt

Tags: qt, xml-parsing, qxmlstreamreader

I am trying to parse the QString which looks like below:

```
<unit>
 <unit_type>110A</unit_type>
 <manufacturer>ABC</manufacturer>
 <article_number>9900</article_number>
 <production_date>2008-05-29</production_date>
 <delivery_revision>03B</delivery_revision>
 <present_revision>03B</present_revision>
 <rev_date>2008-05-29</rev_date>
  <made_the_last_rev>B21</made_the_last_rev>
  <serial_number>530029</serial_number>
 <eth_addresses>
 <eth_address>00:06:30:03:0c:0b</eth_address>
 </eth_addresses>
 <boards>
 <board>
  <board_type>411C</board_type>
  <article_number>9910</article_number>
  <production_date>2008-05-29</production_date>
  <delivery_revision>01A</delivery_revision>
  <present_revision>01A</present_revision>
  <rev_date>2008-05-29</rev_date>
  <made_the_last_rev>B21</made_the_last_rev>
  <serial_number>0460044</serial_number>
  </board>
  <board>200Z4
  <board_type>731A</board_type>
  <article_number>3-474</article_number>
  <serial_number>200Z4</serial_number>
 </board>
 <board>
  <board_type>401B</board_type>
  <article_number>04418</article_number>
  <production_date>2008-05-28</production_date>
  <delivery_revision>01B</delivery_revision>
  <present_revision>01B</present_revision>
  <rev_date>2008-05-28</rev_date>
  <made_the_last_rev>B21</made_the_last_rev>
  <serial_number>1370017</serial_number>
  </board>
  </boards>
  </unit>
  <unit2 version="1" release="0" update="0" evolution="0" >
  <unit_type>4533</unit_type>
  <manufacturer>AH</manufacturer>
  <article_number>34030</article_number>
  <production_date>2017-07-27</production_date>
  <delivery_revision>01A</delivery_revision>
 <present_revision>P2</present_revision>
 <rev_date>2017-07-27</rev_date>
 <made_the_last_rev>CH</made_the_last_rev>
 <serial_number>300000042</serial_number>
<eth_addresses>
 <eth_address>C0:35:80:00:10:96</eth_address>
 <eth_address>C0:35:80:00:10:97</eth_address>
 </eth_addresses>
<boards>
 <board>
 <board_type>MAINBOARD</board_type>
 <article_number>0BEDR</article_number>
 <production_date>2017-07-19</production_date>
 <serial_number>2626</serial_number>
</board>
<board>
<board_type>TIO</board_type>
<article_number>00SMDTOP</article_number>
<production_date>2017-07-15</production_date>
<serial_number>0599</serial_number>
</board>
<board>
<board_type>TFT</board_type>
<article_number>MTI-HL</article_number>
<production_date>2017-07-10</production_date>
<serial_number>31307</serial_number>
</board>
```

My function looks like this:

```
void VrsRequesterWrapper::parseHardwareData(QString pData)
 {
qDebug() << " parseHardwareData ";
QXmlStreamReader reader(pData);
qDebug() << " first Item #1" << reader.name();
if(reader.readNextStartElement())
{
    qDebug() << " first Item #2" << reader.name();
    while(reader.name() == "unit2") {
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #1 " << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #2" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #3" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #4" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #5" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #6" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #7" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #8" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #9" << reader.name();
            reader.skipCurrentElement();
        }
        qDebug() << "DATA VALUE  #10" << reader.name();
        while(reader.readNextStartElement()){
            if(reader.name() == "eth_addresses"){
                while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                    qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Ethernet #1" << reader.name();
                    reader.skipCurrentElement();
                }
            }
        }
        qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Board while #1" << reader.name();
        while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Board while #2" << reader.name();
            if(reader.name() == "boards"){

                qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Board while #3" << reader.name();
               while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #1" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #2" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #3" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #4" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #5" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #6" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #7" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                        if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            qDebug() << "DATA VALUE Boards #8" << reader.name();
                            reader.skipCurrentElement();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

however, I could not manage to parse the "boards" tag completely .. would be nice If I can get some hints to get it don. In addition the number of board tags can varies and some for eth_addresses, for example, the boards tag in above example are 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve it, below is the code snippet .. hopefully it can be helpful for others:

```
void VrsRequesterWrapper::parseHardwareData(QString pData)
 {
QXmlStreamReader reader(pData);

if(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
    if(reader.name() == "unit" || reader.name() == "unit2") {

        while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
             qDebug() << " first Item #1" << reader.name();
            if(reader.name() == "unit_type") {
                qDebug() << "Unit Element " << reader.name();
                 reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "manufacturer") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #1 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "article_number") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #2 " << reader.name();
                    reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "production_date") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #3 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "delivery_revision") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #4 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "present_revision") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #5 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "rev_date") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #6 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "made_the_last_rev") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #7 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "serial_number") {
                    qDebug() << "Unit Element #8 " << reader.name();
                     reader.skipCurrentElement();
            }
            if(reader.name() == "eth_addresses") {
                while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                    if(reader.name() == "eth_address") {
                        qDebug() << "Ethernet Element #1 " << reader.name();
                        reader.skipCurrentElement();
                    }

                }
            }
            if(reader.name() == "boards") {
                qDebug() << "Boards " << reader.name();
                while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                    qDebug() << "Boards #1" << reader.name();
                    if(reader.name() == "board") {
                        while(reader.readNextStartElement()) {
                            if(reader.name() == "board_type") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #2" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "article_number") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #3" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "production_date") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #4" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "delivery_revision") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #5" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "present_revision") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #6" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "rev_date") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #7" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "made_the_last_rev") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #8" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                            if(reader.name() == "serial_number") {
                                qDebug() << "Boards #9" << reader.name();
                                reader.skipCurrentElement();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```